# reading a directory of large compressed zip files

Tags: r, directory, data-analysis

I was wondering if y'all could help me.

I'm trying to read data from a directory containing *332 compressed zips all with about 1000 lines (or more) of data into a data frame*.

I have it so that the directory is set to the file with the zips in it. I figured this way when I tried using the `dir()` function, I could do something like:

```
 d1 <- read.csv(dir()[1:332])
```

to read all the data and then find the mean of say "`columnA`" in that data table by using something like `mean(d1$columnA)`.

Though, so far this has not worked. Any ideas?

I'm operating in **R** with a **Mac OSX**.

Comment: 332 files huh?  Sounds familiar.  This wouldn't happen to be for the Coursera specdata data, would it?  If so just search the SO site for `[r] specdata` and you will find an answer.

Comment: Iterate over the CSV files, `read.csv` each one into a data frame, and then `rbind` it to another data frame containing all your data.

Comment: Do some searching. This question has probably already been asked and answered. The number 332 sort of gives it away. You should be more honest about asking for homework help.

Comment: thanks guys! really appreciate it